# Intellij 14 will not import gradle dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

In IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4, I am working on a large Java EE project that is built with Gradle.  However, when I open up IDEA and attempt to import the project from Gradle, the dependencies do not import (i.e. they do not show up in project settings and I cannot run tests or compile anything).  I have tried running `gradle idea`, both from command line and from within IDEA, as well as refreshing my Gradle projects.  I ran `rm -rf ~/.IdeaIC14/` to reset my settings, just in case anything in my IDEA's Gradle settings was screwy, and I have even gone so far as to reinstall IDEA, all to no avail.  My entire office is running the same version of IDEA and no one else seems to have this problem, and we are all working on the same codebase with the exact same Gradle build files.  Any ideas as to what could cause this?

Comment: `View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle`, you see a sync button, did you try that?

Comment: @karthik Yes, repeatedly.